# How to write correctly in html a table with several rows of a different number of columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am writing in html a table with several rows with a different number of columns. To do that, I am putting several tables, typically each for a specified number of columns.

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<table class="border paddingDefault"  style="width:60%; border-collapse: collapse;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th valign="middle"  width="55%" style="background-color: cyan;" class="column border" ><span style="font-weight: bold;">Name of rule</span></th>
<th valign="middle"  width="5%" style="background-color: cyan;" class="column border" ><span style="font-weight: bold;">Status</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="middle" class="borderTop paddingDefault">The rule name of index 0</td>
<td valign="middle" align="center" class="borderTop paddingDefault" style="background-color: green;">OK</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0px; padding:0; margin:0;">
<td valign="middle" class="borderTop paddingDefault">The rule name of index 0</td>
<td valign="middle" align="center" class="borderTop paddingDefault" style="background-color: red;">KO</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table class="borderNone paddingDefault"  style="width:60%; border-collapse: collapse;border: 0px; padding:0; margin:0;">
<thead>
<th valign="middle"  width="100%"/>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="middle" class="border paddingDefault">the error of index 0<br/>
the error of index 1<br/>
the error of index 2<br/>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

with the following stylesheet:

```
table.middle {
   vertical-align: middle;
}

table.borderNone, th.borderNone, td.borderNone {
   border: none;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.paddingDefault, th.paddingDefault, td.paddingDefault {
   padding: 10px 10px;
}

table.border, th.border, td.border {
   border: 1pt solid black;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.borderTop {
   border-right: 1pt solid black;
   border-left: 1pt solid black;
   border-top: 1pt solid black;
   border-bottom: none;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

It works, but I have a small space between the two rows (in my case, the two html tables), that I can't remove:
[image: Incorrect separation between the rows]
How could I remove this separation?

Comment: Have you considered `colspan`?

Answer (score 0):

You only need add this code to your css:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```